# MYSQL Left Join filtering when child records do not always exist

Tags: mysql

MYSQL

parent table

```
customer
C_Id
First
Last
```

child table

payments

```
P_Id
Paid (logical)
C_Id
```

All customer records do not have a child record in the payment table.
Want to retrieve all customer records except those that have a child record in the payment table `where pay = True` . The data in the logical field paid may be True, False, or `NULL`
So the result set of records will exclude any customers that were already paid.

`Left Join` gives me this:

```
1 Harry Houdini
2 Johnny Bench
3 Clark Gable     Null
4 John Galt       False
5 Nick Cage       True
6 Casey Cason
```

The desired result is

```
1 Harry Houdini
2 Johnny Bench
3 Clark Gable     Null
4 John Galt       False
6 Casey Cason
```

This record does not meet the condition so it is excluded from the query

```
5 Nick Cage       True
```

Comment: Please add in the sample data, the query you've used now and other important information

Comment: If you already have a working left join Query, then just add `WHERE Paid <> True` to get what you want. Please add the query if you want more concrete answers

Comment: Having trouble editing the post. Maybe because it was reformatted by Michael?  New user don't quite understand the interface. When I try to edit I seem to loose Michael's reformatting. He did such a nice job don't want to loose it. If I edit my original post will that delete the reformatting of the question?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * from customer c 
 join payment p 
 on c.c_id = p.c_id where pay = 'false' or pay is NULL;
```

you can't got those output using `left join` because using left join you would got whole table.you can do this using `inner join`